# How to revert back to fglrx-updates driver?

Tags: drivers, 13.10, ati, fglrx

I switched to xorg graphics driver and rebooted but then i faced some error messages so i switched to fglrx proprietry drivr since i read its more stable thab fglrx-updates '!!!', so after installing this stable driver, ubuntu boots into a black screen and i have no other convinient way to search for a soluyion other than uding my phone which is ectremly annoying, your help is very much appreciated.

I basically need to revert back to fglrx-updates driver or whatever so i can login to ubuntu normally again, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On the black screen, press `Ctrl+Alt+F2`.
2. Login with your username.
3. `sudo service lightdm stop`
4. `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`
5. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`
6. Restart typing `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: Thank you but this didnt work. The update is that i see a message box saying that a problem happened and it asks if i want to report it, i chose to report it and then i'm left with cross mouse cursor

Comment: @Muhammad Ok, so you can uninstall fglrx-updates and fglrx. After this, ubuntu will boot with open source drivers.

Comment: @Muhammad But this report box and cross cursor are signals that the drivers you've installed don't support your gpu. If you are on Ubuntu 12.04 you should update it to 13.10 or try to install the driver from AMD/ATI site - a thing that I don't recommend to do.

Comment: weird ! I'm sure I've been using `fglrx-updates` ! I removed it and reverted to xorg drivers and every thing is working now. Thanks a lot :)